# linear regression with insignificant dependent variable

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, t-test, interpretation, regression-coefficients

Before I run a linear regression, I derive my independent and dependent variables. When I run the t-test on my dependent variable itself to test whether it is significantly different from zero or not, I get insignificant t-test result saying that the dependent variable is not significantly different from zero (i.e. insignificant).

However, when I run the linear regression using this dependent variable, I get meaningful results with significant independent variable coefficients.

In this case, should I discard my linear regression results although the coefficients are meaningful? If not, how shall I deal with this?

Comment: Keep the regression and ignore the t test.

Comment: Do you mean I can still utilize the significant coefficient values and interpret them from the regression even in this situation?

Comment: I think so. I don't see what the mean value of the dependent variable has to do with the correlation.